# Regex to find the names in every sentence using python

Tags: python, regex

Hii i am new to regex and stuck with this question.

Q- Identify all of words that look like names in the sentence. In other words, those which are capitalized but aren't the first word in the sentence.

sentence = "This is not a name, but Harry is. So is Susy. Sam should be missed as it's the first word in the sentence."

Here's what i did ...but not getting any output(Excluding the text from begining till i get any capital letter word which is name)

```
    p = re.compile(r'[^A-Z]\w+[A-Z]\w+')
    m = p.finditer(sentence)
    for m in m:
        print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's always only one space after a dot before another sentence begins, you can use a negative lookbehind pattern to exclude names that are preceded by a dot and a space, and another negative lookbehind pattern to exclude the beginning of the string. Also use `\b` to ensure that a captial letter is matched at a word boundary:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\. )(?<!^)\b[A-Z]\w*', sentence)
```

This returns:

```
['Harry', 'Susy']
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this" exactly, but I did notice that I needed to add `\b`.

Comment: In the example sentence, the word *This* is matched as well

Comment: Still don't see what you mean. Can you check the demo and point out what matched? https://repl.it/@blhsing/GleefulLightgreyDimensions

Answer (score 1):

You use a positive lookbehind to look for a capitalization pattern for a word not at the beginning of a sentence.

Like so:

```
>>> sentence = "This is not a name, but Harry is. So is Susy. Sam should be missed as it's the first word in the sentence."
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=[a-z,][ ])([A-Z][a-z]*)', sentence)
['Harry', 'Susy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Imo best done with [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/):

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

sentence = "This is not a name, but Harry is. So is Susy. Sam should be missed as it's the first word in the sentence."

for sent in sent_tokenize(sentence):
    words = word_tokenize(sent)
    possible_names = [word for word in words[1:] if word[0].isupper()]
    print(possible_names)
```

Or - if you're into comprehensions:

```
names = [word
         for sent in sent_tokenize(sentence)
         for word in word_tokenize(sent)[1:]
         if word[0].isupper()]
```

Which will yield

```
['Harry', 'Susy']
```

Answer (score -1):

You're overwriting your `m` variable. Try this:

```py
p = re.compile(r'[^A-Z]\w+[A-Z]\w+')
for m in p.finditer(sentence):
    print(m)
```